# why does it not work to create this snowflake function

Tags: sql, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an SQL that I want to have as a Function. The SQL itself works but when I try to make it into a function it throws error

> Syntax error: unexpected '-'. (line 5)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KEY_GENEREATOR()
RETURNS BIGINT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(REVERSE(replace(cast(cast(current_timestamp as date) as varchar),'-','')),RIGHT(REPEAT('0',12)||(CAST(key_seq.nextval AS VARCHAR(12))),12))AS BIGINT)
';
```

Comment: Don't you have to specify the VARCHAR length?

Comment: @jarlh In Snowflake [VARCHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text#varchar) is equivalent of  `VARCHAR(16777216)` and there is no performance or storage penalty. The entire expression could be greatly simplified which I included in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a syntax error. If your function has too many single quotes it might be easier and safer to wrap the entire SQL statement of your function to the double-dollar quotes.

Try this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KEY_GENEREATOR()
RETURNS BIGINT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(REVERSE(replace(cast(cast(current_timestamp as date) as varchar),'-','')),RIGHT(REPEAT('0',12)||(CAST(key_seq.nextval AS VARCHAR(12))),12))AS BIGINT)
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the use of hyphens in the SQL query. As a workaround, you can try using double quotes to escape the hyphens

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KEY_GENEREATOR()
RETURNS BIGINT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(REVERSE(replace(cast(cast(current_timestamp as date) as varchar),''-'','''')),RIGHT(REPEAT(''0'',12)||(CAST(key_seq.nextval AS VARCHAR(12))),12))AS BIGINT)
';
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is mostly written for human and readability counts. The entire expression could be greatly simplified.

Date reverse is:

```
SELECT REVERSE(replace(cast(cast(current_timestamp as date) as varchar),'-',''));
-- 01303202

=>

SELECT REVERSE(TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYYMMDD'));
-- 01303202
```

and second part is just [LPAD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lpad)

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPEAT('0',12)||(CAST(key_seq.nextval AS VARCHAR(12))),12);
-- 000000000001

=> 

SELECT LPAD(key_seq.nextval,12, '0')
-- 000000000001
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE key_seq;

SELECT CAST(CONCAT(REVERSE(replace(cast(cast(current_timestamp as date) as varchar),'-','')),RIGHT(REPEAT('0',12)||(CAST(key_seq.nextval AS VARCHAR(12))),12))AS BIGINT);
-- 1303202000000000001
```

vs.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE key_seq;

SELECT (REVERSE(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE(),'YYYYMMDD')) || LPAD(key_seq.nextval,12,'0'))::BIGINT;
-- 1303202000000000001
```

---

Wrapping with function and using [dollar-quoted string](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text#dollar-quoted-string-constants) to avoid doubling `'`(source of error in initial function definition):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KEY_GENEREATOR()
RETURNS BIGINT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT (REVERSE(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE(),'YYYYMMDD')) || LPAD(key_seq.nextval,12,'0'))::BIGINT
$$;

SELECT KEY_GENEREATOR();
-- 1303202000000000003
```